# Can I take the output of an exe program and pass that into a vbscript as a parameter

Tags: vbscript

I have an executable program called `conApp.exe`, that retrieves information from BIOS and displays it to the screen as a string of text.

So, if I type `conApp.exe` from an elevated command prompt, I get the text string displayed to the screen

For example;

```
c:\windows\system32>conApp.exe
v1.02.13
c:\windows\system32>
```

Typically I redirect that output to a text file so I can use it in another script.

for example; `c:\windows\system32>conApp.exe > biosVer.txt`

What I would like to do is pass the string of text generated by conApp.exe into variable in a VBScript file and manipulate that text within the VBScript.

for example; `testscript1.vbs conApp.exe`

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

Use WScript.StdIn in your .vbs and feed it via | (pipe):

```
copy con double.vbs
WScript.Echo 2 * CInt(WSCript.StdIn.ReadLine())
^Z

echo 2 | cscript double.vbs
4
```